# Python - Search for Keyword and Print line above

Tags: python

So basically I download and clean up a webpage as best as I can using BeautifulSoup and save it temporarily as a text file that holds data like this:

```
 2123:0335 


WASHINGTON
13
NATIONAL
A85121
THINGLING



 123:4567 


VIRGINIA
12
NATIONAL
A85232
SOMETHIHNG
```

My goal is to search for the keyword "VIRGINIA" and capture the string 123:4567 or whatever numbers that come up as an array. I can pull the lines after the keyword I use, but I get blanks when I try to print the line above. Here is the code I'm using:

```
with open("textfile.txt", "r") as f:
            searchInLines = f.readlines()
            for i, line in enumerate(searchInLines):
                if "VIRGINIA" in line:
                    for l in searchInlines[i:i-3]: print l
```

Any help with this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `searchInlines[i-3:i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("textfile.txt", "r") as f:
    searchInLines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(searchInLines):
        if "VIRGINIA" in line:
            print searchInLines[i-3]
```

Variable name `searchInlines` turned into `searchInLines`.

Arrays referenced properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [line.strip('\n') for line in content if line.strip('\n')]
    if 'VIRGINIA' in content:
        print(content[content.index('VIRGINIA') - 1])
```